# How to get module code as string javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let’s say I have simple component in React and I want to use not only that component itself but the code of it as it is to show on screen ? How can I do that?

Here's what I m doing exactly

```
import Anything from ../../'anywhere';

const CustomComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Anything />
        </div>
    )
}

export default CustomComponent;
```

Then in another file

```
import CustomComponent from './custom-component';

return (
    <div codeHighlightStr={CustomComponentString}>
        <CustomComponent />
    </div>
)
```

I don't know how to get `CustomComponentString` from the same module

Comment: show us some code !

Comment: Something like this? [How to import a .txt file from my source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539756)

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi Please dude. Stop talking. What code you need for this to be more understandable.

Comment: Okay easy easy good luck

Comment: The question doesn't have enough details. This is very specific to your setup which wasn't explained. Is this create-react-app project?

Comment: Yes and I'm using storybook to demonstrate this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReactDomServer.renderToString method or some npm package by query 'jsx to string'

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<xmp>` tag.

```
 render(){
    return (<div>
       <xmp>
       let test='SomeValue';
       document.getElementById('someElement').innetHTML = test;
       </xmp>
    </div>)
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uxu2d6?file=index.js)

Comment: On the same line I was hoping, if I could not only present code inside jsx using <xmp> tag but all of the module including it's import statement. For example, if I wrap my component code as string literal i.e. const Usage = `() => { import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import Accordian from '../../../components/accordian/accordian';
    return (<div></div>)}`,  and then use eval to run that. But it doesn't runs

Comment: Is there a way to re-use all of the module code including import statements as well?

Comment: Updated my question