# React js read file to fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have to read a json file, I followed the following code: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50570949/8024296)

Trying the example shown in the comment, but it's not working for me.

I have to read this file that I have locally, but I'm not succeeding.

Can you give me a hand?

Link: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-9cvtf)

Code:

```
fetch("/user.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => res.results)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    let u = res.map((suggestion, i) => ({
      label: suggestion.email,
      name: suggestion.name.first,
      surname: suggestion.name.last,
      address: suggestion.location.street.name,
      email: suggestion.email,
      picture: suggestion.picture.thumbnail
    }));
    let options =
      inputLength === 0
        ? []
        : u.filter(suggestion => {
            const keep =
              count < 5 &&
              suggestion.label &&
              suggestion.label.slice(0, inputLength).toLowerCase() ===
                inputValue;
            if (keep) count += 1;
            return keep;
          });
    this.setState({ options });
  })
  .catch(e => console.log("Er:", e));
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's happening right now? What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: I would like to read the file.
He does not read it and enters the fetch catch condition.
But if you try the example I posted on codesandbox, you see it immediately.

Comment: Where is the user.json file ? If it's in the public folder, the fetch uri param should be `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL} + "/user.json"`
Actually i tried your CodeSandbox demo, and it works; but it doesn't in your local environment ?

Comment: I have already tried printing the process.env.PUBLIC_URL returns undefined.

Comment: Please update your question description.

Answer (score -2):

You can just use import or require as follows:

```
const data = require("./myFile.json")
import data from "./myFile.json"
```