# Set file into State

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi Friends I'm trying update my state with input.type.file
And after send it into NODEJS route:

```
updateProfileImage = ev => {
    let uploadPic = ev.target.files[0].name;
    console.log(ev.target.files[0]);
    this.setState({profile: uploadPic});
}

<input className="form-control" type="file" multiple  name="profile"
                                                value={this.state.profile} onChange={this.updateProfileImage}
                                                placeholder="Upload Product profile picture" />
```

This is the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.
>
> The above error occurred in the  component:

And here is the nodejs code:

```
router.get('/add-new-product', upload.single('profile'), (req, res) => {

    let product = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        profile: req.file.path,
        cat: {
            catID: req.body.catID,
            catName: req.body.catName
        }
    });

    product.save((err, result) => {
        if(err) res.json(err);
        return res.json(result);
    })
})
```

What I can do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react js handling file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695275/react-js-handling-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

A file input's value attribute contains a DOMString that represents the path to the selected file(s). If the user selected multiple files, the value represents the first file in the list of files they selected.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Value

But 'uploadPic' is only a String.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
 <input type="file" className="form-control" multiple onChange={this.updateProfileImage} placeholder="Upload Product profile picture"  />

updateProfileImage = ev => {
    let uploadPic = ev.target.files[0];
    this.setState({profile: uploadPic});
}
```